# QTP-UFT-Weblist selection by sendkeys-How to keep control key pressed while selecting multiple values

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, hp-uft

Wsh.SendKeys "^"&a(i) is not holding the control down. Something like micCtrldown and micctrlup before and after sending the values would be helpful But not sure about the syntax

```
Set Wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
a = Split(Datatable.Value("AssignedTerminal", dtlocalsheet),",")
 b = ubound(a)
wait 3
Browser("P&D Routing -Estes").Page("P&D Routing Estes").WebList("addAssignedTerminal_Add").Click
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
For i = 0 To b
Wsh.SendKeys "^"&a(i)
 Next
 Set WshShell = Nothing
 Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

Comment: Were you able to determine if this resolved your issue?

Comment: Updated answer...let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Can you update the question with an answer if so and if not, can you provide additional feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Are we sure the SendKeys function supports the concatenated string you are sending it?

```
For i = 0 To b
 Wsh.SendKeys "^"&a(i)
Next
```

Try to use a predefined string to send to SendKeys instead of building it inline.